# Optional Java Builder Functions

Tags: java

I'm working with an imported jar. In that Jar, they only allow builders to create objects.

I.E.

```
public PersonBuilder oneRelation(){
person person = PersonBuilder.builder()
                  .firstName("Tom")
                  .lastName("Smith")
                  .relation(relationObject.builder().Name("Cousin").build())}

public PersonBuilder twoRelation(){
return PersonBuilder.builder()
                  .firstName("Tom")
                  .lastName("Smith")
                  .relation(relationObject.builder().Name("Parent").build())
                  .relation(relationObject.builder().Name("Sibling").build())}
```

I have to create multiple methods to handle having multiple relationships. Unfortunately, if I pass a null to the relation it gives me an error.

Has anyone had any luck dynamically creating a builder? I have modified it a bit to pass in a relation and have the function utilize the size of the relation array. However, I'm still duplicating the firstName and lastName over the total number of relationships I can have.

Comment: 1) You didn't describe what error you get 2) You didn't show us where you are defining the `relationObject` 3) You didn't show us how your PersonBuilder/Person etc classes are defined. Without these, we can't offer suggestion/help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example See this on how to ask a question that will have most chances to be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A builder is just an object so just create a local variable of it and loop through the chained `.relation()` method.

```
public PersonBuilder relations(List<RelationObject> relations) {
  PersonBuilder builder = PersonBuilder.builder()
                  .firstName("Tom")
                  .lastName("Smith");
  relations.forEach(builder::relation);
  return builder;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
relations(Arrays.asList(relationObject.builder().Name("Cousin").build()))

relations(Arrays.asList(relationObject.builder().Name("Parent").build(), 
                        relationObject.builder().Name("Sibling").build()))
```

You can also use varargs so you don't have to create a list:

```
public PersonBuilder relations(RelationObject... relations) {
  PersonBuilder builder = PersonBuilder.builder()
                  .firstName("Tom")
                  .lastName("Smith");
  for (RelationObject relation : relations) {
    builder.relation(relation);
  }
  return builder;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
relations(relationObject.builder().Name("Cousin").build())

relations(relationObject.builder().Name("Parent").build(), 
          relationObject.builder().Name("Sibling").build())
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much.
public PersonBuilder relations(List<RelationObject> relations) {
  PersonBuilder builder = PersonBuilder.builder()
                  .firstName("Tom")
                  .lastName("Smith");
  relations.forEach(builder::relation);
  return builder;
}